# Phonegap onclick executes without click

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I have this code in a phonegap html page:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns" onclick="window.open('http://www.something.com/');">
           <h3>some text</h3>
           <a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.something.com');" class="read-more">read
            more
           </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have a menu page that links to this page (which works fine):

```
<a href="page.html">
  <h2>page</h2>
</a>
```

I build the apk, when I open it on my smartphone, I get the menu. When I click the page item, the page opens, but then the onclick event fires immediately, without even clicking it.

Can someone help me out

Comment: Possible to share entire code logic?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZC9rG/1/

Comment: does it works fine as expected in fiddle?

Comment: it works fine anywhere, also in emulator, but not on the device self

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with how Android webviews handle click actions. It is best not to use onclick if possible. I have had the best luck with the touchstart event but in some rare cases I have had to implement a hack with the following steps:

- onclick/touch append a div element that covers the entire screen and it's z-index is above all elements (but is transparent)
- use setTimeout to remove this div element after 301 milliseconds
- run the action you want to trigger directly after creating the setTimeout method

This is not a great solution, but if nothing else works this will.